# c - Java: UnsatisfiedLinkError on natie method call

Tags: java, c, eclipse, java-native-interface, eclipse-cdt

I'm studying JNI.
I created a simple java class:

```
package asd.jni;

public class PrintJNI {

  public native String print();

  static{
   try{
      System.out.println("loading libPrint");
      System.load("C:/DeLauri/WorkSpaceC_CPP/Print2/Debug/libPrint.dll");  
      System.out.println("libPrint loaded");
  }catch(UnsatisfiedLinkError e){
      System.out.println("error "+e.toString());
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
}
```

Calling manually javah -jni I create asd_jni_PrintJNI.h:

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class asd_jni_PrintJNI */

#ifndef _Included_asd_jni_PrintJNI
#define _Included_asd_jni_PrintJNI
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     asd_jni_PrintJNI
 * Method:    print
 * Signature: ()Ljava/lang/String;
 */
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_asd_jni_PrintJNI_print
  (JNIEnv *, jobject);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

In Eclipse CDT I create a C project called "Print" and inside I create a Print.c:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "asd_jni_PrintJNI.h"

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_asd_jni_PrintJNI_print  (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {

printf("aasdasdadasd");
const char rtn[10]  = "Hello \n";

printf("aasdasdadasd");
return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, rtn);
}
```

Everything compile successfully, but when I run my main class:
    package asd;

```
import asd.jni.PrintJNI;

public class StartPrintJNI {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try{
        PrintJNI print = new PrintJNI();

        System.out.println("call");
        String cStrg = print.print();
        System.out.println("called");
        System.out.println(cStrg);
    }catch(UnsatisfiedLinkError e){
          System.out.println("error in main "+e.toString());
          e.printStackTrace();
      }catch(Exception e){
         System.out.println("2 "+ e.getMessage());
         e.printStackTrace();
     }

}

}
```

I have the followed error:

```
loading libPrint
libPrint loaded
call
error in main java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: asd/jni/PrintJNI.print()Ljava/lang/String;
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: asd/jni/PrintJNI.print()Ljava/lang/String;
at asd.StartPrintJNI.main(StartPrintJNI.java:16)
```

Can someone help me? 
thank you

UPDATE: I'm doing these tests on Windows 7 using MinGW in Eclipse/Eclipse CDT IDE

Comment: Did you check your DLL exported function names? You can use http://www.dependencywalker.com/ to look at it.  Most likely your names are getting mangled.

Comment: This is a good question!The DLL file's name it's libPrint.dll but I'm not sure that the function name inside the dll it's right. I can't install this software on my work's pc, but I will find on google how to see inside dll file.

Comment: If I browse dll generated file through eclipse CDT, I find a method called _Java_asd_jni_PrintJNI_print@8()

Answer (score 0):

When linking your DLL with MingW, use

```
-Wl,--export-all-symbols -Wl,--add-stdcall-alias -m32 -shared
```

to export non-decorated copies of your functions.

Do not change your method signatures; You are masking your issue.

Answer (score -1):

I solved my problem. I had just add an underscore "_" to method definition in "asd_jni_PrintJNI.h" :

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL _Java_asd_jni_PrintJNI_print
(JNIEnv *, jobject)
```

therefore change method's name in "Print.c":

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL _Java_asd_jni_PrintJNI_print  (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
```

Comment: This is incorrect.  With MingW, you need to export non-mangled aliases for you DLL